# webdriver.promise.controlFlow equivalent wd.js

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd

I'm using yadda as my BDD tool and was using the webdriver example included in yadda as a basis of my selenium tests.  I'm switching over to wd.js and I'm wondering what the equivalent for this is with wd.js?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching to wd.js have you seen [Moonraker](https://github.com/LateRoomsGroup/moonraker) from LateRooms? It still uses webdriver and yadda under the hood, but provides a [geb](http://www.gebish.org/) like page object pattern on top.